# make error 2 on Windows when building fastText

Tags: makefile, build, gnu-make

I'm trying to build fastText (Facebook's library for learning of word representations and sentence classification) and have tried followed the instructions on their Github page:

`$ git clone git@github.com:facebookresearch/fastText.git
$ cd fastText
$ make`

I installed GnuWin32 and added to the path in order to use the make function. I'm on Windows 10.

However I get the following error:
`$ make
c++ -pthread -O3 -funroll-loops -std=c++0x -c src/args.cc
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, c++ -pthread -O3 -funroll-loops -std=c++0x -c                                  src/args.cc, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [args.o] Error 2`

Anyone has an idea on how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: do you have `c++` available in your path? try typing `c++` and see what happens.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre You're right. I don't have it available. It says `command not found` . I installed clang as per the instructions. Should it suffice or do I need to install c++ separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting this question Facebook clarified that FastText only builds on Mac OS and Linux distributions. See https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar errors when attempting to build fastText on Windows using MinGW tools. I went instead to use Visual C++ 2015 to build fastText and it worked fine after a few tweaks. I submitted a Pull Request for this change https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/pull/39

I also maintain a binary build of fastText for Windows. You can find it at http://cs.mcgill.ca/~mxia3/FastText-for-Windows/

> FastText’s authors do not currently support building and running on Windows. There were attempts to run with Bash for Windows and MinGW. This unofficial build is compiled with Visual C++ 2015 to run natively on Windows